# Counting distinct digits

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

Is there any efficient way to find out the count of distinct digits from a given number in constant time or O(Logn)?

Suppose `n = 1234` the count should be `4` (As there are `4` distinct digits)

if `n = 1121` the count should be `2` (As there are `2`distinct digits i.e `1, 2`)

Constraint: `0 <= n <= 1000000007`

Comment: Just iterate over the digits, since all numbers have at most 10 digits, this is not that much of an issue.

Comment: Most of languages can cast numbers to string why not using this ?

Comment: The best complexity you can achieve is O(d) where `d` is number of digits in your number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

```
int DistinctDigits(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool[10] digitFound = {false};

    while (n > 0)
    {
      d = n % 10;
      n = n / 10;

      if (!digitFound[d])
      {
        result++;
        digitFound[d] = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that you have to think about what to do with leading zeroes (including when n == 0).

Answer (score 3):

use map with key as digit and value as it's count. now the size of the map will be your answer.
or
use set, since set does not contain a duplicate element size of the set will be your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since the numbers are (relatively) small, we can just convert these to a string, pass these through a uniqness filter, and calculate the number of elements. For example in Python:

```
def nuniqdigits(n):
    return len(set(str(n)))
```

Converting to a string is relatively expensive, we can iteratevly enumerate the digits as follows:

```
def digits(n):
    if n:
        while n:
            yield n % 10
            n //= 10
    else:
        yield 0
```

so then we can calculate the number of distinct digits as:

```
def nuniqdigits(n):
    return len(set(digits(n)))
```

Since the possible values for digits is limited, we can use a bitmask here. For example in Haskell:

```
import Data.Bits((.|.), popCount, shiftL)
import Data.Word(Word16)

nuniqdigits :: Int -> Int
nuniqdigits n = popCount (foldr (.|.) (0 :: Word16) (map (shiftL 1) (digits n)))
    where digits n | n <= 9 = [n]
                   | otherwise = uncurry (flip (:) . digits) (divMod n 10)
```

A number *n* has *O(log n)* digits, and since we make iterations in the number of digits, and all operations are constant in each iteration, this runs in *O(log n)*.

Comment: @cdlane: sorry, that should be `yield` :) in C# it is `yield return`...